# How to store a array as node property in neo4j database?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm new in neo4j database with node.js. so I don't know how to store array type value in neo4j as node property.

Mention following array and I need to store this array into node property

```
friends: [2,3,8,9]
```

suppose I have a one Team node it's considered few properties like `name`, `last name`, `friends`, etc.. but `friends` property is an array.

Is it possible to store array into node property, if yes then how?

Comment: You should share what you have done so far and what are the issues you are facing instead of asking how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and very simple.

Check the following query:

```
CREATE (:Node {name: 'node A', friends: [2,3,8,9]})
```

> I recommend adding relationships for defining friendships instead of
>   storing the list of friends as property.

Comment: friends array is an id array when I get this friends property it's returning string not an array.

Comment: How are you storing in Neo4j? Above query works as expected and returns me array.

Comment: It's difficult to say anything unless you share what you are doing?

Comment: hello, raj, you are right but how can I add new value and delete array item in friends list?